# visreg package for R: conditional plots

Tags: r, regression

The `visreg` package in R can produce plots for various regression models. When creating conditional plots for each predictor, the other predictors are — by default — held at their median values, although this value can be changed by the user. In the [documentation](http://myweb.uiowa.edu/pbreheny/publications/visreg.pdf), an example is given (Fig. 5) that shows the effect of choosing values other than the median. The model's predictions change depending on the chosen value, as do the data that are plotted. My question is this: how are the data transformed between these plots? Are they simply adjusted according to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional plot shows [partial residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_residual_plot) and not the original data as I thought. Consequently, the points that are plotted are determined according to the equation given in that URL.